# get normal from raycast hit with object orientation taken into account

Tags: python

Whenever I have a normal from a raytrace hit on an object face it's "randomly" rotated around its local Z.

success, hit_location, hit_normal, face_index, object, matrix_world = scene.ray_cast(bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph, origin, direction)

[image: sample random nature of raycast normal]

I'm trying to mimic "builtin.primitive_cube_add", which takes the object orientation into account as well.
(see illustration screengrab.) The box on the surface is from builtin.primitive_cube_add.  Mine is the orange rectangle.  Always different.

How can I get a reliably orientated normal vector ?